# Reading data from lake

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I need to read data from azure data from azure data lake and apply some joins in sql and show in Web UI.
Data is around 300 gb and migrating data from azure data factory to azure sql database is happening at the speed of 4Mbps.
I have also tried to use sql server 2019 which has polybase support but that is also taking 12-13 hours to copy data.
Also tried cosmos db for storing data from lake but seems it is taking large amount of time.

Any other way we can read data from lake.
One way can be azure data warehouse,but that is too costly and support only 128 concurrent transactions.
Can databricks be used,but its a computation engine and we need it to be available 24*7 for UI Queries

Comment: ADLS Gen 1 or 2?

Comment: @Sam Cogan -ADLS Gen 1

Comment: Is there any way to bulk copy from data lake

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? The whole point of data lake is that you leave the data there and report and analyse it in place, so why do you want to move it?

Comment: @SamCogan - Quite a common use case to transform data lake content and, after transforming, landing it in an OLTP or data warehouse. The OP didn't say data was being moved; they mentioned performing SQL joins (so... transforms).

Comment: Have you tried increasing parallelism of your ADF pipeline, or increasing Data Integration Units, to increase throughput? Did you confirm that your SQL Database instance (or Cosmos DB collection) isn't being throttled due to DTU/RU exhaustion?

Comment: @David Makogon-I have tried parallelism on ADF Pipeline but still not getting much througput.Yes,cosmos db is throttled while I am copying but I have kept 100000 du,how much du can I keep.

Comment: Please double check how you are loading into sql azure. We did a blog post on this recently here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SQL-Customer-Success-Engineering/Optimize-Azure-SQL-Database-Bulk-Upsert-scenarios/ba-p/781075

Comment: @DavidMakogon what I read from the question is that the user wants to perform some join’s on the data and then report on it, seems a waste to copy the data to sql to do this when it can be done in place

Comment: @SamCogan - ADLS isn't optimized for queries like an OLTP is. Different use cases. Imagine you need to work with your data in a graph-based arrangement (something Cosmos DB, or Neo4j, handle natively and very efficiently). Imagine you want to perform point-reads directly to specific JSON-based documents, based on a set of properties (something that Cosmos DB, or MongoDB, handle natively and very efficiently). Or SQL in the OP's case. A data lake is not optimized to be an OLTP. Maybe the data transformed into an OLTP is only a subset; only lives for *x* months; etc. But no, it's not a waste.

Comment: @DavidMakogon-Since I need to show the data in UI,I need to copy data somewhere in sql or cosmosdb and copying 300 gb of data itself is taking so much time.Any other way we can achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I still suggest you using Azure Data Factory. As you said, your data is around 300 gb.

Here's the [Copy performance and scalability achievable using ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#copy-performance-and-scalability-achievable-using-adf):

[image]

I agree with David Makogon. The performance of your Data Factory is very slowly( 4Mbps). Please reference this document [Copy activity performance and scalability guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance).

It will help you improve the Data Factory data copy performance, give more suggestions about Data Factory settings or Database settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: already gone through this,but able to increase only from 1 to 4 mbps,not much :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar situation, just more data +-900GB. 
If you need to show it in ui, you will still need to load data to Azure SQL, as DWH is not very good at handling parallel load and its costy.
We ended up using bulk insert from blob storage.
I created sp to call bulk insert with parameters (source file, target table) and ADF to orchestrate and run in parallel.
Could not find anything faster than that.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver15